# Determine provider of IQueryble(Object)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

Is it possible to determine if an `IQueryable<Object>` is a LINQ-to-sql object or not? (Has a SQL statement as its source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) returns `System.Data.Linq.Table<T>`s (`IQueryable<T>`) or `System.Data.Linq.ITable`s (`IQueryable`), so you can test whether your IQueryable instance `is` one of these.

---

**Edit:**

When a Linq operation (like `Select`, or `OrderBy`) is applied to the `IQuerable` the result is a `System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`. This is an internal type, so you cannot use the `is` operator. In stead, do `` y.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1") ``.

Comment: And when the object is Anonymous type? Like:
var y = from x in db.TableX select new { Field1 = x.SomeField, etc. };

Comment: In that case, `y` should be a `System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`